# JQgrid search not working when cell contain HTML data in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have added JQgrid on page and Jqgrid contain HTML content in one column, but search functionality not working for this column

Comment: Where is performed the search? - locally or at server? Do you use custom formatter to add the html content? There is a missing a lot of important information.

Comment: I have performed search locally

Comment: I have used html editor to add html content

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: I am using jqGrid  4.4.4

Comment: Can you please publish a demo demonstrating the problem and describe how you change the content. After you change the content do you perform a save to that content to the local data - saveRow, saveCell or other method to store the data in grid? Whitout demo code I can't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.